# An exception started throwing after switching QUEUE driver in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I have started getting errors after switching my queue driver in my Laravel app from 'database' to 'sqs'. The error is following:

> Method __PHP_Incomplete_Class::handle() does not exist

I  have not done any other changes besides switching the queue driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the error. The reason is that I have accidentally connected the app to the queue of another app. And because the second app does not have the job classes from the first app it has thrown errors.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Haven't tried this solution yet though